# React Nuka carousel vertical align slides

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel

I have a carousel that has slides with images but the slides is not aligned vertically. I usually use flex-box to align items but it's not possibly now due to the images are in a nested structure now. Is there the a way to vertically align the slides in [Nuka](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/nuka-carousel)?

```
<div class="container__container" style="flex-wrap: wrap; margin: 1em 0px 1.5em; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/universal-avenue/image/upload/c_fill,co_rgb:c0c4cb,dpr_auto,e_colorize,f_png,q_auto/v">
</div>
```

when i apply display: flex instead of display: block to slider-list in the console the images become vertically aligned

Comment: Paste some code, and if you can create a jsfiddle with your problem.

Comment: i would just use flex box to align different items but now that use nuka carousel it's not possible because of nested structure created nuka

Answer (score 0):

Just add the vertical attribute to your Carousel like this:

```
<Carousel vertical={true}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nuka carrousel doesn't provide a vertical version of the carrousel you can use react swipeable it does nevertheless the structure to provide the element is quite different nuka is a way better to implement non static element from a back what you can do if its youre case is to work on nuka open source community and add vertical carrousel or just get along with the horizontal one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).